# When does duplicate rule job run?

Tags: duplicate-management

We had a duplicate rule setup but it looks like it wasnt set up correctly and there were a lot of duplicate record sets created. we have corrected the issue with the Duplicate rule setup .

We ended up deleting all the existing Duplicate record sets.

The question that i have is when would the duplicate rule job run based on the new criteria? I dont see an option for running the duplicate job. Is there a way we can run the job or would it be running on its own? if yes how often would it run?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When initially activated, it will run asynchronously and you'll get an email when the process is complete. For new records, it will run during the DML process to block potential duplicates. You need to make sure both the Matching Rule and Duplicate Rule are activated in order for things to work. If it's not running as expected, you can check the logs for more information.

Comment: The issue here is that its an existing rule which i have made changes to the rule and want to rerun it. would that be possible?

Comment: @Prady The system manages this for you. As long as it is active, it should run.

Comment: It's been four hours since the change was made and there is no new duplicate sets. I am wondering whether this happens only after on change of record as the initial job had run on when the duplicate rule was first activated.